# Spark Memory Usage Concentrated on Driver / Master

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I'm currently developing a Spark (v 2.2.0) Streaming application and am running into issues with the way Spark seems to be allocating work across the cluster. This application is submitted to AWS EMR using client mode, so there is a driver node and a couple of worker nodes. Here is a screenshot of Ganglia that shows memory usage in the last hour:

[image]

The left-most node is the "master" or "driver" node, and the other two are worker nodes. There are spikes in the memory usage for all three nodes that correspond to workloads coming in through the stream, but the spikes are not equal (even when scaled to % memory usage). When a large workload comes in, the driver node appears to be overworked, and the job will crash with an error regarding memory:

`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x000000053e980000, 674234368, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)`

I've also run into this:
`Exception in thread "streaming-job-executor-10" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` when the **master** runs out of memory, which is equally confusing, as my understanding is that "client" mode would not use the driver / master node as an executor.

Pertinent details:

- As mentioned earlier, this application is submitted in client mode: `spark-submit --deploy-mode client --master yarn ...`.
- Nowhere in the program am I running `collect` or `coalesce`
- Any work that I suspect of being run on a single node (`jdbc` reads mainly) is `repartition`'d after completion.
- There are a couple of very, very small datasets `persist` into memory.
- 1 x Driver specs: 4 cores, 16GB RAM (m4.xlarge instance)
- 2 x Worker specs: 4 cores, 30.5GB RAM (r3.xlarge instance)
- I have tried both allowing Spark to choose executor size / cores and specifying them manually. Both cases behave the same. (I manually specified 6 executors, 1 core, 9GB RAM)

I'm certainly at a loss here. I'm not sure what is going on in the code to be triggering the driver to hog the workload like this.

The only suspect I can think of is a code snippet similar to the following:

```
      val scoringAlgorithm = HelperFunctions.scoring(_: Row, batchTime)
      val rawScored = dataToScore.map(scoringAlgorithm)
```

Here, a function is being loaded from a static object, and used to map over the `Dataset`. It is my understanding that Spark will serialize this function across the cluster (re: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#passing-functions-to-spark). However perhaps I am mistaken and it is simply running this transformation on the driver.

If anyone has any insight to this issue, I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue. Here's how I addressed it:

I made an incorrect assertion in stating the problem: there was a `collect` statement at the beginning of the Spark program.

I had a transaction that required `collect()` to run as it was designed. My assumption was that calling `repartition(n)` on the resulting data would split the data back amongst the executors in the cluster. From what I can tell, this strategy does not work. Once I re-wrote this line, Spark started behaving as I expected and farming jobs out to worker nodes.

My advice to any lost soul who stumbles across this issue: don't `collect` unless it's the end of your Spark program. You can not recover from it. Find another way to perform your task. (I ended up switching a SQL transaction from `where col in (,,,)` syntax to a join on the database.)